# Showing all http connections in vm instance

Tags: apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform, http, netstat

I have a Google Cloud VM instance running Debian and a dockerized Apache httpd inside. I'm trying to count all the http connections in the machine.

I run this:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do netstat -at | wc -l; sleep 0.2; done
```

and then I run multiple concurrent http requests, using JMeter, but count doesn't change.

If I execute it inside the Apache container, it works fine because traffic is forwarded to the container. But I would like to see it in the host machine. Is this possible?

Comment: netstat is showing you socket details. Since the sockets are opened in the container and not in the host, netstat running in the host, cannot list sockets in the container.

Comment: IIRC mod_status shows number of accesses/connections, have you tried checking that instead? You would just have to compare the numbers between checks to see how many there have been.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether your issue has been resolved or not?